# Марки мобильных телефонов

Tags: имена-собственные

Здравствуйте!
Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно писать марки мобильных телефонов: в кавычках ли, с большой ли буквы?
Например: "Он звонил ей со своей *нокии*"
И нет ли тут аналогии с написанием марок машин?

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, есть ли четкие рекомендации на этот счёт, но я бы писал в кавычках и с заглавной, по аналогии с марками других технических изделий (автомобилей, например), не приобретших нарицательного значения: *со своей "Нокии"*.

Оговорюсь, что речь идет о написании русскими буквами и без номера (иначе возможно написание типа *Нокия-7777*) и что в подобных вопросах не всегда аналогии помогают, так что на истину в последней инстанции ответ не претендует.

Answer (score 0):

Очень часто выручает прием проведения аналогии. Например:" Я был в кинотеатре "Радуга". Я звонил из "Радуги". Это верно. Значит, если телефон "Нокия", то звонил  с "Нокии". Хотя вызывает сомнение правильность самой фразы. Почему не просто:"Звонил со своего телефона".